# String to array, split by new lines and brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

I have large string block which I need to split into arrays based on if they're wrapped in brackets or separated by new lines.

Input:

```
[this is block
this is also same "block"
this is same block

another same block]
new block!
another new block!
[this is new block
this is also a new block]
```

One of the many things I've tried:

```
$block_lines = preg_split('/\[([^]]+)\]|\r/', $block_content);
```

Expected result:

```
Array
(
  [0] => 'this is block
  this is also same "block"
  this is same block

  another same block'
  [1] => 'new block!'
  [2] => 'another new block!'
  [3] => 'this is new block
  this is also a new block'
)
```

Actual result:

```
Array
(
  [0] => 'new block!'
  [1] => 'another new block!'
  [2] => ''
)
```

Comment: I don't recommend `preg_split()` for this because you need to pair the `[` with the `]`.

Comment: It looks like you are using curly braces instead of square braces in your pattern.  `\R` will get `\r\n` and `\n`.

Comment: To start this `\{` will not match `[` , it just won.t.  In other words `\{([^}]+)\}` matches `{tag}` not `[tag]`

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I tried doing a variation with curly braces in case I was getting confused with the multiple square brackets. Edited it back to the version I was trying with square brackets (still incorrect), but I've accepted the correct answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex in `preg_split`:

```
/\[([^]]+)]|\R/
```

It splits the string on either a string of characters inside `[` and `]`, or on a newline. By using the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag, we can capture the contents of the `[]` as well:

```
$string = '[this is block
this is also same "block"
this is same block

another same block]
new block!
another new block!
[this is new block
this is also a new block]';
print_r(preg_split('/\[([^]]+)]|\R/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE));
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => this is block 
this is also same "block" 
this is same block

another same block
    [1] => new block!
    [2] => another new block!
    [3] => this is new block
this is also a new block
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/WTIe6)

Answer (score 1):

Match all square braces matches first (which may contain new lines) else match a single line.

The reason that I am favoring `preg_match_all()` over `preg_split()` for this case is because in plain terms, you aren't actually intending to perform dynamic explosions but to find matches.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/pbtOf))

```
$text = '[this is block
this is also same "block"
this is same block

another same block]
new block!
another new block!
[this is new block
this is also a new block]';

var_export(preg_match_all('~\[[^\]]*]|.+~', $text, $matches) ? $matches[0] : 'nothing');
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '[this is block
this is also same "block"
this is same block

another same block]',
  1 => 'new block!',
  2 => 'another new block!',
  3 => '[this is new block
this is also a new block]',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, to change the phrasing of your logic, you wish to explode on all newlines that are not inside of a square bracketed expression.  You can use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` to match and disregard the bracketed expressions, and explode on all newlines that make it through the filter.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZbhjS))

```
var_export(preg_split('~\[[^\]]*](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\R~', $text));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '[this is block
this is also same "block"
this is same block

another same block]',
  1 => 'new block!',
  2 => 'another new block!',
  3 => '[this is new block
this is also a new block]',
)
```